# How to sort MongoDB by a field that has numeric value in python mapping?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mapping in Python project:

```
color_map = {Red: 1,
             Yellow: 2,
             Green: 3}
```

How to sort MongoDb collection (in aggregate pipeline) by **color** field, according to mapping above?

```
{_id: 1,
 color: Red,
 name: Pony},
{_id: 2,
 color: Green,
 name: Unicorn},
{_id: 3,
 color: Yellow,
 name: Mole}
```

What I expect after aggregate sorting by color is:

```
[{_id: 1, name: Pony},
 {_id: 3, name: Mole},
 {_id: 2, name: Unicorn}]
```

If that is relevant - I am using mongoengine primarily

Comment: I might add a field "color_weight" using $addFields, but how do I do that with the *color_map* ?

Comment: So a document looks something like `{'_id': 1, 'color_map': {'Red': 1, 'Yellow': 2, 'Green': 3}}`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No I updated how it looks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand better, but it's still not clear to me exactly what, or how you want to sort.  Would you show a few documents (like a small example collection), and then also the desired sorted output?  Maybe if I see the the before/after I'll understand better.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I updated with expected result, thanks for waiting though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "colorRank": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "color_map": [
              {"color": "Red", "rank": 1},
              {"color": "Yellow", "rank": 2},
              {"color": "Green", "rank": 3}
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "rank",
              "input": {
                "$first": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$color_map",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$color", "$$this.color"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"colorRank": 1}
  },
  {
    "$unset": ["color", "colorRank"]
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d78CnehRMtZ).

Comment: I think that works, though seems a bit bulky, thanks a lot

Comment: @robertmollet Yeah, it is a bit bulky, but I wanted `"color_map"` easily identifiable and editable in case the sort criteria changes.  A specialized sort could be made more concise.